# Show that $G$ is not solvable.

Tags: group-theory

Let $p = 2k + 3$ be a prime number $\ge 5$. Let $G$ be a subgroup of $S_p$ containing a $p$-cycle and an involution $g$ that fixes exactly three elements, i.e., a product of $k$ disjoint transpositions. Can I conclude that $G$ is not solvable? If so, how?

---

**EDIT 1:** If $p = 5$, then $g$ is a transposition, so $G$ is actually all of $S_5$, which is known not to be solvable. But what about the general case?

---

**EDIT 2:** Let's attack this problem from a different angle. Let $g \in S_p$ be an involution and let $h \in S_p$ be a $p$-cycle. Write $G = \langle g, h \rangle$ and $H = \langle h \rangle$.

Then the following propositions are equivalent:

- $ghg$ is a power of $h$.
- $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.
- $H$ is the only Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$.

(I am still stuck here.)

Comment: You should know by now that this is not how one asks a question on this site.

Comment: @Shaun: Actually, I don't. Care to elucidate?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @Shaun: I deliberately hid the larger context, because I don't want people to help me with the larger problem I am working on.

Comment: What are you studying? What text is this drawn from, if any? If not, how did the question arise? What kind of approaches (to similar problems) are you familiar with? What kind of answer are you looking for? Basic approach, hint, explanation, something else? Is this question something you think should be able to answer? Why or why not?

Comment: See [X Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and its answer on how to avoid it.

Comment: I really don't know if my comment will help you, but I have two ideas: you may try to show that [G,G]=G, that is, G is perfect; or you may try to show that G contains a non-solvable subgroup. Is the subgroup generated by the p cycle and the involution solvable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can conclude that $G$ is not solvable, and many of your assumptions are unnecessary.

Let $p$ be prime, and let $G$ be a solvable subgroup of $S_p$ containing a $p$-cycle. Then $G$ is transitive and hence primitive, so its nontrivial normal subgroups are transitive.

Let $P$ be a minimal normal subgroup of $G$. Then $P$ is abelian and transitive, so $|P|=p$, and hence $G$ is contained in the normalizer of $P$ in $S_p$, which is a $2$-transitive group of order $p(p-1)$ in which no non-identity element fixes more than one point